# How to create a new channel using nextcord

Tags: python

I believe it goes something like this

```py
@bot.command()
async def ticket(ctx, member, name):
  await create_text_channel(name = f'{member}', subject = "test channel")
```

Please correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
async def ticket(ctx, channelName):
    guild = ctx.guild

    embedTicket = nextcord.Embed(title = "Ticket", description="Sehr gut!")
    if ctx.author.guild_permissions.manage_channels:
        await guild.create_text_channel(name=f'{channelName}-ticket')
        await ctx.send(embed=embedTicket)

This would be a way to do it.
```